# «Город Я» как сокращение от Ялты. Писать с точкой?

Tags: орфография, названия, сокращения

Название выставки «Город Я» как сокращение от Ялты. Писать с точкой?

Comment: Это надо знать, почему так названа выставка — возможно, здесь обыгрывается тема "город Ялта и я".  Может быть, кавычки можно поставить: Город "Я".

Answer (score 2):

Я никогда не сталкивалась с текстом, в котором бы город Ялта "подвергался сокращению" (чего там сокращать-то — всего четыре буквы).
Возможно, что такое название выставки — это стилизация под [город N](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4_N).
Возможно, что это отсылка собственно к местоимению "я" (город с именем Я).

В любом случае использование буквы "Я" никак не является сокращением. А названий особенных, нестандартных, не подпадающих ни под одно правило, — предостаточно:
выставка ["Я люблю П"](https://bublik.delfi.ee/news/culture/vystavka-ya-lyublyu-p-v-tallinne?id=60773037) (то ли я люблю букву "п", то ли я люблю Пермь);
время Ч, час Ч;
предприятия "Город Ю" (г. Юрга), "Чистый город Ц" (г. Набережные челны);
"ЗооСадЪ" (музыкальный альбом);
газета «Коммерса́нтъ-Daily» (до 1992 года просто «Коммерсантъ», сокращенно «Ъ»).

P. S. Конечно же, в особых случаях сокращения до одной гласной существуют:
у. е. (условная единица), т. е. (то есть), и. о. (исполняющий обязанности), а. е. (астрономическая единица).

Comment: Добавлю ещё вполне законный пример сокращения слов до первой буквы: в словарных статьях различных словарей полностью слово принято писать только в заголовке статьи, а далее — первая буква с точкой.

Comment: Конечно-конечно, Медведик, Вы правы — такое оформление есть в словарях (и некоторых других текстах). Но к названию выставки это никак невозможно "приделать". Фантазеры ялтинцы, однако.

Answer (score 2):

Если выбрано такое условное наименование, то точка обязательна для обозначения *факта сокращения*: иначе буква будет восприниматься как местоимение в названии (если же оно намеренно обыгрывается - другое дело) или присвоенная литера (пункт А, план Б, павильон К). С Яковом и Ярославом никто не спутает, но из контекста должно быть ясно, что город - не Ярославль (если дело в Крыму затевается, этого достаточно).

Пример стандартного сокращения названия города до одной буквы (без видового наименования) можно встретить в *библиографических ссылках*, непосредственно перед названием издательства: М. = Москва.

Answer (score 0):

На гласной не может быть сокращения. И точка как знак сокращения не прочитается. Можно выделить букву курсивом или каким-либо иным (вне правил пунктуации и правил выделения) образом. <Я>; =Я=; Я с подчёркиванием и т. п.

Comment: Но ведь "то есть" иногда сокращённо пишут как "т. е."!

Comment: В своем ответе, Артём, я привела и другие примеры сокращения до одной гласной (кроме "т. е.").

Comment: О конкретном случае речь — об одинокой гласной. Причём прописной.

Comment: Ой, Римма, простите, не посмотрел!